# Java Static constructor not working

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

Here is my code

```
class Bomb {
    static String description = "bomb description";
    static int id = 1;

    private String name;
    private int size;

    public static void Bomb() {
    id++;
    System.out.println(" " + description + " " + id);

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
   }

    public void printout() {
        System.out.println(" " + name + size);
    }
}

public class array {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Bomb.Bomb();
        Bomb detenator = new Bomb();
        Bomb destroyer = new Bomb();
        destroyer.setName("hr4");
        destroyer.setSize(43);
        detenator.setName("m1s");
        detenator.setSize(34);

        detenator.printout();
        destroyer.printout();

    }

}
```

I want the description to print with each bomb object. but the description prints by itself.
any one got any idea how to fix that?
also please suggest any alternative ways I could've written this code, but don't make it to complicated. i just started learning java so i probably wont understand complex stuff.

Comment: Aside from the fact that there's no such thing as a static constructor, what are you expecting the line that says `Bomb.Bomb();` to do?

Answer (score 3):

I short, there are no "static constructors".

You may want something that references a static member, like this:

```
public Bomb() {
    id++;
    System.out.println(" " + Bomb.description + " " + id);
}
```

Please go over the [Java tutorial of constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of constructor is completely messed up.

1. As @Reut Sharabani mentioned there is no something like static constructor. You are using constructors to initiate object of a class. And static let you use method just by calling `ClassName.staticMethod()` without creating object of the class (one ruling out another). If static constructor would exist you would be able to write something like, for example, `ClassName.ClassName()` which make no sense.
2. Constructors are not returning any value, so declaring them as void is an error. Again constructor is used to initialize your object with some values (but unnecessary)

Comment: @extremly_new_to_coding I apreciate your thank you, but would be nice if you accept my answer and vote it up.